# Using Google APIs in Android app with more than one developer / machine

Tags: android, google-api

I'm writing an Android app with three other developers (for a school project) that makes use of various Google APIs. I set up my SHA1 key in the Developer Console  with the correct package name and I can access the APIs just fine from the app when it's launched through my Android Studio.

Now, my teammates are trying to get their local copies to work that they just pulled from our repo and the APIs aren't working (403 and SIGN_UP_REQUIRED errors).

What's the right way to set up their app so that they can run and test locally? And will I run into similar issues with the release-apk of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you need to add a new set of credentials for every machine / developer on your team, along with a set of credentials for the release-apk.

### Developers Setup

Open your Google Developer Console and go to APIs and Auth > Credentials. In there, do "Add credentials" for everyone on your team - use the same package name that's in your code, but use each individual developer's unique SHA1 key (which you get by having them all run this): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqgak.png

Now, everyone on your team should be able to run the app locally by launching through Android Studio and have access to all the Google API calls being made from within the app.

### Release-apk Setup

For the release version, you'll have to generate the signed release-apk through Android Studio, along with the corresponding keystore. Then, follow the same steps as the image above, but this time instead of using the android-debug path, point to where your *.jks is stored.

Now you'll be able to distribute the release-apk and anyone will be able to run it and it'll work properly with all the Google API calls!

Comment: Or just copy the same debug.keystore onto everyone's computer.

Comment: Go to the same page you did when you created your api key, for each developers, add their sha1 fingerprint (they can easily find this in Android Studio logcat error when they tried to use the API). Use the same package name...no code changes are needed.